# Play framework 2.5 app in production in docker container is throwing errors on startup

Tags: scala, guice, production, playframework-2.5

Below error is thrown while running the docker image in production: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[info] o.h.v.i.u.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the     following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.AppController. Classes     
must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero- 
  argument constructor that is not private.
  at controllers.AppController.class(AppController.scala:18)
  while locating controllers.AppController
    for parameter 5 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:59)
 while locating router.Routes
 while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
 while locating play.api.routing.Router
 for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>   
(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
 while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
 while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
  for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
 at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
 while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
 while locating play.api.Application
```

Comment: Some code would help a lot :)

Comment: looks like a code issue.

Comment: does it work locally? maybe some conflict with the jdk version ?

Comment: Well, what constructors does `controllers.AppController` have?

Comment: yes it does work locally during dev.

Comment: class AppController(val cache: CacheApi, val     configuration: Configuration, val environment: Environment)
      extends Controller {

      def get() = Action.async(parse.empty) { => implicit request =>
    
        Future(Ok)
      }
    }

Comment: inside conf/routes

GET /get controller.AppController.get

Comment: class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  override def load(context: Context): Application = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach(_.configure(context.environment))
    new AppComponents(context).application
  }
}

class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with EhCacheComponents {

  lazy val appController = new controllers.AppController(defaultCacheApi, configuration, environment)
  ....

Comment: override def router: Router = new _root_.router.Routes(httpErrorHandler, appController)

  val gzipFilter = new GzipFilter(shouldGzip =
    (request, response) => {
      val contentType = response.header.headers.get("Content-Type")
      contentType.exists(_.startsWith("text/html"))
    })

  override lazy val httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(gzipFilter)

}